# Scanf double in C not giving the right value

Tags: c

I would like to know where is my mistake. 
When scanning the parameters as doubles , and immediately printing them (for checking), the print is not giving me the values that I entered.
I tried to define them as integers and it worked, but for doubles its just giving me this: `a=0.00000`, `b=-0.00000`

take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{  
    double a=0,b=0,c=0;

    scanf("%lf",&a);
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    scanf("%lf",&c);

    printf("%lf %lf\n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: sorry i didnt include my whole code , this is the whole code, but it still gives me the same thing.

Comment: Your code compiles, but with warnings, because you leave out `include` statements. Compile with `-Wall` to turn on all warnings.

Comment: Thats erroneous code and not well formatted. You are missing  `#include` statements and the validity of `int main()` instead of `int main(void)` is implementation defined. Furthermore you miss a return for your function.

Comment: You might define the main function as `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, and add `#include <stdio.h>` to the top of your file.

Comment: I updated my code , I didn't include it all at first , excuse me.

Comment: @Basilm Can not reproduce your problem. Running it with Input "12.00/n13.00" will return "12.00/n13.00". See: https://ideone.com/VHqCPi

Comment: A complete problem description not only states the code and *observed* output (which you did), but **also** the *input* and the *expected output* (which is missing). Make this a kind of mental checklist when posting here, filing a bug report etc.

Comment: Probably not the cause, but I believe `%lf` is pointless (possibly wrong?) with `printf`; the `%f` format code already handles `double`s, the `l` either means nothing, or might be making it look at the completely wrong register (if it tries to interpret it as meaning "use an architecture specific long double register instead of the normal location").

Comment: Works just fine for me

Comment: The code is perfectly valid

Comment: @ShadowRanger isn't it like the `l` in `lf` should be _ignored_?

Comment: always check the return value of input funcions! `if (scanf("%lf", &b) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: I don't observe the claimed behavior. You should include: your inputs, your outputs, expected output (and possibly also which compiler you uses etc). Also make sure that the posted data should match - claiming that it outputs `a=0.0000`, `b=0.0000` doesn't give a good impression since the source doesn't even try to output `a=...` and `b=...`.

Comment: im obviously printing a and b in the line before the return. I try to input any possible number (integer , double , 1 , 2) and still prints 0.0000 as a and -0.0000 as b.

Comment: @Basilm: If you observe one thing, and everybody else here observes something different, either your code or your environment differs from everybody else. Make sure you are actually using the binary compiled from the source you posted, *and please tell us your compiler brand and version*.

Comment: @Basilm: compile your actual code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Read the documentation of every used function (notably of [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)...). Check against runtime errors (so use the result item count of `scanf`). Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 3):

Written as it is, your program will accept correctly formatted input for 3 floating point values and will print the first two.

What values do you enter?

What is the **precise** input you type into your program?

I suspect you type extra characters: `scanf` stops scanning on invalid input.

You should test the return value from the `scanf` function calls and verify that values were actually parsed.

Incidentally, the `printf` format for `double` arguments is `%f`, not `%lf`, but this should not pose a problem as the extra `l` is most likely ignored.

Here is a corrected version you should try to find out where the problem lies:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    if (scanf("%lf", &a) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input for a\n");
    }
    if (scanf("%lf", &b) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input for b\n");
    }
    if (scanf("%lf", &c) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input for c\n");
    }
    printf("a=%f b=%f\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello there , this is not my goal to just scan and print. But due to the errors that i got, I tried writing a new program just to check if the problem is occuring from my coding or something else. So i tried just scanning and printing to see if the scan is receiving the right values. For example: I type 3 to 'a' , 4 to 'b' and 5 to 'c' , I receive "0.0000 , -0.0000".

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. Each point is actually spot-on, including the check of `scanf()` return value (!).

Comment: @Basilm:  We are aware that you skimmed down the problem to its core.  Yet your program does not show an obvious reason for the problem you describe.  Beyond the issues I mentioned in the answer, the input you give the program might be the cause. What characters do you type **exactly**.  What is your environment? How do you run the code?